# Unexpected behavior of complex Firestore rules

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm having issues with rules in firestore and subsequently querying the data from flutter. I've created a few simple collections
with some sample code to illustrate my issues. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Actually, my current rules work, but there is some unexpected behavior. Something I came accross by random and solved my problem. I like to know why. Is it a bug? Or is it expected behavior for which I'm missing the specifications?

I've tried to document my case as I believe it might help others as it can be seen as an example of more complex rules.

**1. Collections**

**1.1 Test**

I'm trying to limit the documents that people can read. For this question, I've called the collection for these documents "Test". I want some documents to be accessable by everybody, where some documents should only be accessible by some specific members. Documents with readCondition = 1 are public. Documents with readCondition = 2 are accessible by logged in users but their access is limitted to the privilegeLevelRequired. I have actually another level of complexity that privileges depend on the app (within the app). This is indicated with the appId. So, fields in collection Test are:

```
    - appId
    - privilegeLevelRequired
    - readCondition
```

**1.1.1 Example data**

| Document ID | appId | privilegeLevelRequired | readCondition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| asdasddsa | TEST1 | 1 | 2 |
| test1 | TEST1 | 0 | 1 |

**1.1.2 Screenshot**

[image]

**1.2 Test3**

To specify which user has which privilege, member privilege fields are stored in collection Test3. For each appId in our app, in this collection we have an entry.  The document ID is the appId. Each entry has a subcollection "Access". The fields in this collection aren't relevant, but for now I have:

```
    - appId
```

**1.2.1 Example data**

| Document ID | appId |
| --- | --- |
| TEST1 | TEST1 |

**1.2.2 Screenshot**

[image]

**1.3 Test3/Access**

This collection is used to store member privilege information. The document ID is the firebase UID. Fields are:

```
- privilegeLevel
```

**1.3.1 Example data**

For the document in Test3, the subcollection Access contains

| Document ID | privilegeLevel |
| --- | --- |
| 8WzyDzQta1Tqvit9fmrdcHsYUVF2 | 1 |
| WzKImODx6WYVqdSW3D9Az3xrUnM2 | 1 |

**1.3.2 Screenshot**

[image]

**2. Rules**

**2.1 In words**

In the below rules I

- allow read when readCondition is 1

  OR
- allow read when readCondition is 2 and the document's privilegeLevelRequired == the privilegeLevel of the member for that app

**2.2 In code**

```
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /Test/{id} {
            allow read: if    
                            // Read condition 1 means: everybody can read the docs
                            (resource.data.readCondition == 1) 
          
                            ||
                            
                            // Read condition 2 means: logged in users with sufficient privilegeLevel can read the docs
                            (resource.data.readCondition == 2)
                             && (request.auth != null)
                             && (resource.data.privilegeLevelRequired == (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Test3/$(resource.data.appId)/Access/$(request.auth.uid)).data.privilegeLevel))
        }
      }
    }
```

**3. The example app**

I run this app after having logged on with user with firebase UID 8WzyDzQta1Tqvit9fmrdcHsYUVF2

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<String> myTest() async {
    try {
      var collection = Firestore.instance.collection('Test');
      // QUERIES HERE
      var query = collection.where("readCondition", isEqualTo: 2).where("privilegeLevelRequired", isEqualTo: 1);//.where("appId", isEqualTo: "TEST1");
      //var query = collection.where("readCondition", isEqualTo: 1);
      // END QUERIES HERE
      await query.getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.documents){
          print(ds.documentID);
        }
      });
      print("Done");
      return "Done";
    } catch (Exception) {
      print(Exception);
      return "Exception";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Start");
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => myTest(),
              child: new Text('Click me'),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**4. The queries**

When one would want to read all the documents that person has access to, a number of queries would need to be run and the resulting documents
would all have to be merged. The reason is that we can't use OR statements in querying, so hence merging results is required. But again, to simplify
things I'm not doing that here now.

In the above statement app, in between QUERIES HERE, I have the following queries

**4.1 Query for public available documents**

**4.1.1 Query**

```
var query = collection.where("readCondition", isEqualTo: 1);
```

**4.1.2 Results**

```
test1
```

**4.1.3 Comments**

This is expected

**4.2 Query for privileged documents, attempt 1**

**4.2.1 Query**

```
var query = collection.where("readCondition", isEqualTo: 2);
```

**4.2.2 Results**

PERMISSION_DENIED exception. This is expected as the query needs to be expressed in the form of the rules (at least my understanding)

**4.2.3 Comments**

This is expected

**4.3 Query for privileged documents, attempt 2**

**4.3.1 Query**

```
var query = collection.where("readCondition", isEqualTo: 2).where("privilegeLevelRequired", isEqualTo: 1);
```

**4.3.2 Results**

PERMISSION_DENIED exception. This is NOT expected as the query is expressed in the form of the rules

**4.4 Query for privileged documents, attempt 3**

**4.4.1 Query**

```
var query = collection.where("readCondition", isEqualTo: 2).where("privilegeLevelRequired", isEqualTo: 1).where("appId", isEqualTo: "TEST1");
```

**4.4.2 Results**

```
asdasddsa
```

**4.4.3 Comments**

This is perhaps the expected result.

QUESTION 1: However the question is: WHY did I have to add .where("appId", isEqualTo: "TEST1"); to make this query possible? Why was the query specified in 4.3 not working?

By the way: even though the privilegeLevelRequired is part of the rules, it must also provide it in the query. That's expected. So my app will retrieve this value from the Access collection prior to querying the data.

**5. Variations**

**5.1 Variation 1**

A variation of the abrules that I would prefer is to be able to have various levels of privileges. Access to these documents would depend on the member's privilegeLevel. Actually this is my case. So I would prefer this:

```
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /Test/{id} {
            allow read: if    
                            // Read condition 1 means: everybody can read the docs
                            (resource.data.readCondition == 1) 
          
                            ||
                            
                            // Read condition 2 means: logged in users with sufficient privilegeLevel can read the docs
                            (resource.data.readCondition == 2)
                             && (request.auth != null)
                             && (resource.data.privilegeLevelRequired <= (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Test3/$(resource.data.appId)/Access/$(request.auth.uid)).data.privilegeLevel))
        }
      }
    }
```

**Questions**

QUESTION 2: When I use any of the below queries, I get PERMISSION_DENIED exceptions. Why?

```
      var query = collection.where("readCondition", isEqualTo: 2).where("privilegeLevelRequired", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 1);
      var query = collection.where("readCondition", isEqualTo: 2).where("privilegeLevelRequired", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 1).where("appId", isEqualTo: "TEST1");
```

**5.2 Variation 2**

Given variation 1 doesn't work, I am forced to do a variant. If a member has privilegeLevel 3, I would query with the following queries:

```
var query = collection.where("readCondition", isEqualTo: 2).where("privilegeLevelRequired", isEqualTo: 1).where("appId", isEqualTo: "TEST1");
var query = collection.where("readCondition", isEqualTo: 2).where("privilegeLevelRequired", isEqualTo: 2).where("appId", isEqualTo: "TEST1");
var query = collection.where("readCondition", isEqualTo: 2).where("privilegeLevelRequired", isEqualTo: 3).where("appId", isEqualTo: "TEST1");
```

This works with the following rules:

```
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /Test/{id} {
            allow read: if    
                            // Read condition 1 means: everybody can read the docs
                            (resource.data.readCondition == 1) 
          
                            ||
                            
                            // Read condition 2 means: logged in users with sufficient privilegeLevel can read the docs
                            (resource.data.readCondition == 2)
                             && (request.auth != null)
                             && (resource.data.privilegeLevelRequired == (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Test3/$(resource.data.appId)/Access/$(request.auth.uid)).data.privilegeLevel))

                            ||

                            (resource.data.readCondition == 2)
                             && (request.auth != null)
                             && (resource.data.privilegeLevelRequired == (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Test3/$(resource.data.appId)/Access/$(request.auth.uid)).data.privilegeLevel -1))

                            ||

                            (resource.data.readCondition == 2)
                             && (request.auth != null)
                             && (resource.data.privilegeLevelRequired == (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Test3/$(resource.data.appId)/Access/$(request.auth.uid)).data.privilegeLevel -2))
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: hi Johan,   On question 1 are you especting for a user to be able to get data from more than one app simultaniously?  if not it makes sense to pass the app id as well.

Comment: Hi Soni. That is correct indeed: we can have multiple apps and a user can have access to multiple apps. However. The Access entry of app 1 sits in document App/1/Access/[that user], where the Access entry of app 2 sits in App/2/Access/[That user]. So, we shouldn't even have to have appId inside Access.

Comment: it is intended the need to specify which app because on Firestore when quering for collection `Access` you will get both Access collections. `App/1/Access/` and  `App/2/Access/`